# Subclassing dataclass fails to override default arguments

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I'm failing to override a default kwarg.

```
n [13]: from dataclasses import dataclass

In [14]: @dataclass
    ...: class D1:
    ...:     name: str = "foo"
    ...: class D2(D1):
    ...:     name: str = "bar"
    ...: D2().name == "foo"  # WTF
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: Did you mean to make `D2` a `@dataclass` as well?

Comment: @Mark Yep. It doesn't make any difference whether I add it or not.

Comment: When I decorate `D2` with `@dataclass` `D2().name` becomes `"bar"`. This makes sense because without it you are inheriting the `__init__` from `D1` provided by the dataclass.

Comment: Yeah, you just forgot the `@dataclass`. [Adding it fixes things.](https://ideone.com/1BhRv2)